# ¿Abrir un zip del proyecto web con la herramienta Kudu de azure?

Tags: aplicación-web, azure, zip

Estoy tratando de restaurar un proyecto de azure, utilizando la herramienta de desarrollo Kudu. El problema es que no he logrado descomprimir el .zip que  contiene al proyecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Lo intentado con el comando Expand-Archive pero no he tenido éxito, agradecería mucho si alguien conoce el comando o la forma correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se sube un .zip a la consola de kudu, una vez se termina el upload del zip, automáticamente kudu descomprime el zip en el path de destino del zip.

Tenía mis dudas, pero acabé de probar antes de escribir esta respuesta y funciona así.

[image: Kudu console]